# UIAlertController Crash Error

Tags: swift, swift4, uialertcontroller

Here is my code

```
let selectRoute = UIAlertController(title: "Select a Route", message: "Please select the route you want to create your trip on", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let route1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Route 1", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.reminder()
        self.routeID = 1
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    let route2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Route 2", style: .default) { (action) in

    }

    selectRoute.addAction(route1)
    selectRoute.addAction(route2)

    if let popoverPresentationController = selectRoute.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
        popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = self.view.bounds
    }

    self.present(selectRoute, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I run this, the actionSheet just appears just over the Navigation Controller really small, anyone know a fix?

Comment: How are you presenting the `UIAlertController`?

Comment: Let me guess: Crash on iPad, no? Did you look for the error?

Comment: @Larme Yes the thread 1 signal sigabrt error

Comment: Are you trying to display an alert or an action sheet because the `UIAlertController` can do both?  The alert will not generate the error but the action sheet will because it needs to be anchored to something as the error is indicating.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth an action sheet

Comment: I thought so.  On an iPad an action sheet is displayed as a popover and so must be anchored to some other view i.e. where does its arrow point to.  This can be done by either specifying a specific `UIBarButtonItem` or a `UIView` and the `CGRect` within that view.  As the error and answers say you can do this using the `barButtonItem` or `sourceView` and `sourceRect` properties of it's associated `UIPopoverPresentationController` before presenting or by doing the same in the `prepareForePopoverPresentaton` method of the view controller presenting it.

Comment: If possible @UpholderOfTruth could you give some example I'm a little confused and all the other answers don't work for me

Comment: The answer provided seams clear enough to me.  The only way to make it clearer is for you to post the code your are using to display the `UIAlertController` so that an example can be specific to your usage.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth the problem with the answer is i'm not using a tab bar controller

Comment: The answer as it is now isn't specific to a tab bar controller it just uses self.view and self.myButton.frame but you can adjust them to what you want.  As I said to make it clearer you need to post the code your are using with some explanation.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Ok, i've updated it

Comment: That has changed the entire question as it's no longer about crashing.  From looking at your code you are anchoring to self.view and the entire bounds of it so the `UIAlertController` is trying to be outside it resulting in your small size.  What is the user tapping to actually show the alert controller.  Using that as the anchor is probably more appropriate.

Comment: The alert appears in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iPad the alert will be displayed as a popover using the UIPopoverPresentationController, it requires you define an anchor point for the presentation of the popover using either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.

To support iPad, include this code:

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.myButton.frame
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

here is an example:
Suppose you have a button and you are going to show alert controller below of the button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myBtn: UIButton!

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title :)", message:"message...", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "delete", style: .destructive) { (action: UIAlertAction) in
        //Do something
    }

let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "...", style: .default) { (action) in
        //do something
    }

alertController.addAction(addAction)
alertController.addAction(deleteAction)
alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.myBtn.frame
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you are displaying the action sheet after the user makes a selection on a cell within a UITableView. you can use this code:

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = cell
alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = cell.bounds
```

Comment: No does not work, and also will this still work on iPhone?

Comment: @BobHenderson yes It will work on both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: What is "cell" supposed to be?

Comment: @BobHenderson in my example I wanted to show the alert on my tableview cell. Forget about it and just set a sourceRect and a sourceView. something like this:     alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
                alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = myRect

Comment: what's myRect meant to be?

Comment: @BobHenderson I edited the answer, please see it again :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by using a barbuttonitem property, could you explain further? where should I connect this from?

Comment: I'm not using a tab bar controller so what do I link my barbuttonitem to?

Comment: @BobHenderson I saw your code, you need to determine where do you want to present the popover, based on your code (popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = self.view.bounds) It depends on your view because you use the view bounds for presenting popover. Try to set a custom rect like this popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200) then you can find out the difference.

Comment: yeah so I tried that, any way to make it bigger?

Comment: @BobHenderson Are you saying the actionSheet size is smaller than the standard size? because It has a standard size and look in apple ecosystem and I don't think you can change it. Are you running on iPhone or iPad?

Comment: well on the ipad it's the same as iphone size but anyway to make it look visually better such as bigger on the ipad?

Comment: @BobHenderson I think there is no way to change it, but you can create a custom alert controller, like this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-alert-controller-in-ios-10-swift-3--cms-27589